# What does "You have the right to an attorney" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, legalese

Does attorney means lawyer? and What does **"You have the right to an attorney" mean**?

Comment: In the US it means a lawyer.  In the UK the term "attorney" is rarely used and hasn't officially been used since the 1870s.  The US and UK governments each have a senior official called the Attorney General, though.  Today the role is of more importance in the US than the UK (where some of its former functions now belong either to the Justice Secretary or to the Director of Public Prosecutions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an attorney is a lawyer who works in a court of law and the whole thing refers to something called [**the Miranda warning**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning). That's the phrase you hear when you get arrested by the police. And the expression ***you have the right to an attorney*** just means that you have the legal right to use the professional service of an attorney to protect yourself in court and if you can't afford one, he or she will be provided for you.

Comment: You might want to knote that the precise language is from the Miranda warning, but the right itself is from the Sixth Amendment to the US Constitution.